# server doesn't send response for Sequelize many to many relationship query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, many-to-many

I am new to sequelize and node js. I have been trying to implement Sequelize Many-to-Many Association using node.js, express with PostgreSQL database following [this](https://www.bezkoder.com/sequelize-associate-one-to-many/) tutorial. I have implemented a single table and retrieve data correctly without any issue. But in many-to-many relationships, I can only print data to console and in postman and chrome, it keeps loading around a minute and wait without loading data. Here are my code files.

db config file

```
    const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  operatorsAliases: false,
  define: {
    timestamps: true,
    freezeTableName: true
  },

  pool: {
    max: dbConfig.pool.max,
    min: dbConfig.pool.min,
    acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
    idle: dbConfig.pool.idle
  }
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.actor = require("./actor.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.film = require("./film.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.film_actor  = require("./film_actor.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);



db.film.belongsToMany(db.actor, {
  through: db.film_actor,
  as: "actors",
  foreignKey: "film_id",
});
db.actor.belongsToMany(db.film, {
  through: db.film_actor,
  as: "films",
  foreignKey: "actor_id",
});


module.exports = db;
```

filmController file

```
const db = require("../models");
const Film = db.film;
const Actor = db.actor;


//find all films including actors
exports.findAll = () => {
    return Film.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: Actor,
          as: "actors",
          attributes: ["first_name", "last_name"],
          through: {
            attributes: [],
          }
        },
      ],
    })
      .then((film) => {
         console.log(film[5]);
        return film;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(">> Error while retrieving films: ", err);
      });
  };

  // find film by film id
  exports.findById = (req, res) => {
    const film_id = req.params.id;

    return Film.findByPk(film_id, {
      include: [
        {
          model: Actor,
          as: "actors",
          attributes: ["first_name", "last_name"],
          through: {
            attributes: [],
          }
        },
      ],
    })
      .then((films) => {
        return films;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(">> Error while finding film: ", err);
      });
  };
```

film.route file

```
module.exports = app => {
    const film = require("../controllers/film.controller.js");
  
    var router = require("express").Router();

     // Retrieve all films
     router.get("/films", film.findAll);
  
    // Retrieve a single actor with id
    router.get("/films/:id", film.findById);
  
      app.use('/api', router);
  };
```

server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const filmController = require("./app/controllers/film.controller");


const app = express();

const db = require("./app/models");
db.sequelize.sync();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to bezkoder application." });
});


db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  // run();
});

require("./app/routes/actor.routes")(app);
require("./app/routes/film.routes")(app);


// app.get('/films',filmController.findAll);

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

As per my understanding, the issue should be about the routing. I created route for many to many associations as the same way I did for singe table(actor) but this problem occurred. I put a console log under findAll() method in  filCcontroller and it prints the data in the console along with the query.

This is the output on my console

```
    Executing (default): SELECT "film"."film_id", "film"."title", "film"."description", "film"."release_year", "film"."language_id", "film"."rental_duration", "film"."length", "actors"."actor_id" AS "actors.actor_id", "actors"."first_name" AS "actors.first_name", "actors"."last_name" AS "actors.last_name" FROM "film" AS "film" LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "film_actor" AS "actors->film_actor" INNER JOIN "actor" AS "actors" ON 
"actors"."actor_id" = "actors->film_actor"."actor_id") ON "film"."film_id" = "actors->film_actor"."film_id";
film {
  dataValues: {
    film_id: 166,
    title: 'Color Philadelphia',
    description: 'A Thoughtful Panorama of a Car And a Crocodile who must Sink a Monkey in The Sahara Desert',
    release_year: 2006,
    language_id: 1,
    rental_duration: 6,
    length: 149,
    actors: [
      [actor], [actor],
      [actor], [actor],
      [actor], [actor],
      [actor]
    ]
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    film_id: 166,
    title: 'Color Philadelphia',
    description: 'A Thoughtful Panorama of a Car And a Crocodile who must Sink a Monkey in The Sahara Desert',
    release_year: 2006,
    language_id: 1,
    rental_duration: 6,
    length: 149,
    actors: [
      [actor], [actor],
      [actor], [actor],
      [actor], [actor],
      [actor]
    ]
  },
  _changed: Set {},
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    include: [ [Object] ],
    includeNames: [ 'actors' ],
    includeMap: { actors: [Object] },
    includeValidated: true,
    attributes: [
      'film_id',
      'title',
      'description',
      'release_year',
      'language_id',
      'rental_duration',
      'length'
    ],
    raw: true
  },
  isNewRecord: false,
  actors: [
    actor {
      dataValues: [Object],
      _previousDataValues: [Object],
      _changed: Set {},
      _options: [Object],
      isNewRecord: false
    },
    actor {
      dataValues: [Object],
      _previousDataValues: [Object],
      _changed: Set {},
      _options: [Object],
      isNewRecord: false
    },
    actor {
      dataValues: [Object],
      _previousDataValues: [Object],
      _changed: Set {},
      _options: [Object],
      isNewRecord: false
    },
    actor {
      dataValues: [Object],
      _previousDataValues: [Object],
      _changed: Set {},
      _options: [Object],
      isNewRecord: false
    },
    actor {
      dataValues: [Object],
      _previousDataValues: [Object],
      _changed: Set {},
      _options: [Object],
      isNewRecord: false
    },
    actor {
      dataValues: [Object],
      _previousDataValues: [Object],
      _changed: Set {},
      _options: [Object],
      isNewRecord: false
    },
    actor {
      dataValues: [Object],
      _previousDataValues: [Object],
      _changed: Set {},
      _options: [Object],
      isNewRecord: false
    }
  ]
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.